# Convert source code from one language to an other?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers

Say I have a full application written in Python. Is it feasible to convert the source code into C? If such a tool doesn't exist, why doesn't it? What are the constraints?

I ask this since I have been wondering why people use C for microcontrollers when they could write their code uber-fast in Python when prototyping and then convert the source.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html) for Python in particular. But it also gives hints as to the general problems that are associated with compiling a high-level dynamic language to something like C.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/why-arent-there-automated-translators-from-one-programming-language-to-another

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question but it's already been answered on [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/12475/123050).

Comment: I claim the Programmers SE link is not useful for this question.  First of all the question there is much more general, asking about translation between _any_ two Turing complete languages.  Second the answers there are all either irrelevant (because they are answering the more general question) or wrong.

Comment: The top 3 answers to http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29589/7459 are _much_ more interesting (and correct (and even maybe relevant to you)) than the answers on the Programmers SE question.

Comment: I accidentally found this link that might be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler