# Why don't we recognize Python as a compiler-based language?

Tags: python

I just read this [Why doesn't Python need a compiler?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136942/why-doesnt-python-need-a-compiler)

I know that Python isn't absolutely compiler or interpreted but it is both of them it's maybe an interpretive, high-level, and all-purpose programming language. Python uses PVM(interpreter) and Bytecode(that is output of a compiler). after all, **why do we classify Python as a compiler language in comparison to C for example?** **what does make Python different from C which is quicker than Python?**

Comment: I think this is offtopic here. Why didn't you post your question on [softwareengineering.SE] where you found that other one?

Comment: @Raphael Oh you're right I thought there is no difference then I'll put it there

Comment: I think this is useful background to understand the topic: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29589/what-properties-of-a-programming-language-make-compilation-impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation process is a process of taking code from language "A" and translating it to code from language "B".

---

Lets start by saying that python doesn't compile at all - it stays python code all of the time.

On the other hand, $C$ compiles into assembly, which then turns into a standalone executable.

Since python stays python, this means that to run python code, you will need a special program - an interpreter. This interpreter reads the python code line-by-line, and executes it. But $C$ compiles into assembly, which is natural for the computer and can be executed without requiring help from other programs.

While creating an interpreter is usually simpler, a compiler is a much better option - here are a few advantages:

- Compiled code doesn't need to rely on external programs to run code
- The compiler can catch some errors even before the program is executed, while this is not possible when using an interpreter
- A compiler is capable of introducing optimizations into the compiled code, so that it will run faster (nowadays, its *significantly* faster!)

---

All of that being said, even though python is an interpreted language, it doesn't make it a bad one. The core concept of python is being simple, easy to learn and use, and still powerful - and python achieves those well.

---

### Important note

In this answer I was talking about the most basic versions and usages of python and $C$. Yes, you can create a compiler for any language, even python. And yes, python already isn't a "fully" interpreted language - there are some compilation steps that are done. But it is still considered an interpreted language since there really isn't a native compiler that translates it into machine code (assembly)

Comment: Python converts the code into some intermediate representation. It's not stored as text. You can even compile python code into "python bytecode".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus please feel free to edit my answer and correct whatever you deem necessary! I tried in my answer to amplify the differences, so there is a good chance I might have oversimplified some things (and hence they won't be correct)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you, sir. but i don't understand what is the reason that python doesn't use just a native compiler by itself?

Comment: @nirshahar Thank you I realize it now. so we know python is easy to read and learn, this could be because it doesn't use a native compiler? i just wonder

Comment: Not really, but it does have a (small) part in it. One thing that this interpreter enables, is dynamic types. This means that a single variable isn't bound to have a particular type all of the time - it could sometimes be an integer and other times a string. Practically, this allows for simpler syntax which helps the language to be easier to learn and master.

Comment: Asked on [so]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557438/why-cant-pure-python-be-fully-compiled